# Python: How can I print a string where one column has a fixed width?

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting, fixed-width

I am trying to print strings in the following format:

```
   1). Tim     Brazil
   2). Johnny  Argentina
   3). Sara    Ukraine
```

However, they always end up printing like this:

```
   1). Tim  Brazil
   2). Johnny  Argentina
   3). Sara  Ukraine
```

What can I do to fix it so that the columns are aligned such as the first example?

I tried
`print('{0}). {1} {2:>11}'.format(i, name, country))` with no success. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Wrong column. Try `print('{0}). {1:<11} {2}'.format(i, name, country))`

Comment: This did the trick; thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

(moving comment to answer)

You are formatting the wrong column.

Try this code:

```
print('{0}). {1:<11} {2}'.format(i, name, country))  # left justify second column
```